Router - Angular vs React
I want the SPA to redirect by default to /page1. Is React's {path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/page1" />} equivalent to Angular { path: '/', redirectTo: 'page1' } or is there a better way to do it?
import { Navigate, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";
import page1 from "./pages/page1";
import page2 from "./pages/page2";

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/page1" />},
      {
        path: "/page1",
        element: <page1 />,
      },
      {
        path: "/page2",
        element: <page2 />,
      }
    ],
  },
]);




Yes, pretty much, but don't forget to include the replace prop in the Navigate component so the action is REPLACE instead of PUSH so it's actually a redirect.

@DrewReese - Thanks for replace prop explanation
